# Enable PDF fast web view using Java?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How do I enable fast web view property of a PDF using Java code or any open source Java libraries?

*Note: this is also known as a "linearized PDF".*

Comment: care to comment on my latest answer about PDFclown? It seems that would suit your needs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out any of these:

- [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)
- [gnujpdf](http://gnujpdf.sourceforge.net/)
- [PDF Box](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)
- [FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)
- [JFreeReport](http://www.jfree.org/jfreereport/)
- [PJX - (site appears to be down)](http://www.etymon.com/epub.html)
- [JPedal](http://www.jpedal.org/)
- [PDFJet](http://pdfjet.com/os/edition.html)
- [JPod](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpodlib/)
- [PDF Renderer](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries/pdf-renderer)
- [Big Faceless](http://big.faceless.org/products/pdf)

Hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way of structuring a PDF. If you are trying to enable it, you will need to rebuild the PDF - you can't just set a flag.

Comment: Thanks, mark can you known how can i rebuild my pdf using java code so i can make it linearized( enabling fast web view )

Answer (score 2):

there's an open source tool, called QPDF, which is content preserving and very fast. In Unix you'd use the following command to linearize:

```
qpdf --linearize input.pdf output.pdf
```

it shouldn't be too hard, to call this in Java it seems to me...

Full documentation on this free open sourced tool is [here](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html#ref.advanced-transformation)

edit: [PDFclown](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/index.html) offers serialization also with linearized support now - see http://www.massapi.com/source/PDFClown/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/files/SerializationModeEnum.java.html

Comment: Thanks for solution, but i don't want to use any tools. i need open source java library that fulfill my requirement.

Comment: the tool I mentioned is open source and has an open source C++ library, surely you must be able to link and reuse that in Java

Comment: Can i do without this tool. i don't want to use any tool even it is open source i just need java open source library.

Comment: like i said - you can use the library that's described in the docs

Comment: i made an edit - you want to have a look at PDFclown, which is not so well known, but does what you want it to do and more AND is a Java library